# python selenium check existing or not

Tags: python, selenium

hi I want check if my code exists get "src" or put 0

```
try:
    img.extend(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#question-0 > img").get_attribute('src'))
finally:
    img.extend([0])
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code? do you get an error? If so, what is it? If not, how is the output different than you want.

Comment: I think what you really want is `img.append(0)` and `image.appned(driver.find...)`

Comment: I get error Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#question-0 > img"}
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.121)

Comment: some element have image but not all of them and I want get that image

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the error message.

Answer (score 0):

```
element = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#question-1 > div > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) > p:nth-child(2) > img")

if len(element):
    img.extend([element[0].get_attribute('src')])
else:
    img.extend([0])
```